# Normalizing this database: what would be ideal in this scenario?

Tags: database-design, normalization

I'm designing a game where a character has many items and those items can be of many types.  There is a character table, and twelve different tables of possible items broken down by type (such as weapons, armors, and various other item types).

I want to make a table to hold instances of these item types (basically a characters' items table) every row will have a foreign key from the characters' table to indicate which character has ownership of that item.

At first I figured I'd make foreign keys in the characters' items table -- one key for each of the twelve item tables.  But since every item can be of only one "type," that would lead to eleven null fields in every row, and that seems wrong.

What would be the better approach?  I've yet to build the database, so I can entertain other inventory ideas that don't use twelve item tables, but know this:  the admin interface will allow a user to add/remove/modify items of each type as needed.

Also, I'd like to stick to the best normalization practice, so I'll ignore the inevitable "Who cares?  Just do what works and use null-able fields."

Comment: Best normalization practice is not always best programming practice. In particular, anything that would require you to query 12 tables when you can guarantee you'll only return rows from 1 of them is not best programming practice, no matter how compact and non-redundant your data set is. What are your priorities for this system?

Comment: @Kylotan +1 - normalisation should always be applied, but it is a balancing act, in theory you can normalise right up to the Nth degree, but by this time you will have many tables, slowing down your query performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd first check if you could unify those twelve tables into one.  Start with [Single-Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html), because it's simple and I bet it would be adequate in this case.

```
CHARACTER --<- CHAR_ITEMS  ->-- ITEM_TYPES_STI
```

If not, try [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html).  Basically, define a supertable for "item type" and the character's items reference that.  Each sub-table for the 12 individual item types also reference the item types supertable:

```
CHARACTER --<- CHAR_ITEMS  ->-- ITEM_TYPES_SUPER --- ITEM_TYPE_SWORDS
```

Re your comment: I've clarified the line above.  The relationship between item_types_super and item_type_swords should be 1:1.  That is, for each row in swords there should be a distinct row in super.  The way to do this is to make the foreign key in swords also its primary key.

But not every row in super has a row in swords.  The row in super could be referenced by a row in shield, or axes, or whatever.  But only by one subtype.  The idea is that columns common to all item types belong in super, and the columns that are subtype-specific go in each subtype table.

Comment: If I understand your second example:  A character has many char_items, an item_type_super has many char_items and item_type_swords.  If the admin inserts a few swords in the item_type_swords table, and a row in the char_items table has a key that maps to a "sword" type in the item_types_super table, how can I tell which sword from the item_type_swords table this item is intended to be?

Comment: Thanks, I'll run with it and see what happens!

Answer (score 1):

If you used the following tables (I only included the key values for columns).  The CHARACTERS_ITEMS table contains the list of items for each character.  The combination of ItemTypeID and ItemID would be used to reference a row in one of the 12 items tables.

```
CHARACTERS
----------
CharacterID (PK)

ITEMS
-----
ItemID (PK)

ITEM_TYPES
----------
ItemTypeID (PK)

CHARACTERS_ITEMS
----------------
CharacterID (FK)
ItemTypeID (FK)
ItemID (FK)
```

Here is the beginning of a view that may be helpful as well.  It demonstrates how the ItemTypeId can be used to reference the appropriate table.

```
CREATE VIEW v_character_items
AS
SELECT {list of columns}
FROM character_items
JOIN character_item_1 on character_items.ItemID = character_item_1.ItemID and character_items.ItemTypeID = 1

UNION 
SELECT {list of columns}
FROM character_items
JOIN character_item_2 ON character_items.ItemID = character_item_2.ItemID and character_items.ItemTypeID = 2

UNION
{other tables...}
```

Comment: I'm reviewing your design to see if it works for me, but I've gotta say:  Why use `UNION`?  I believe you should look into learning `JOIN` syntaxes.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen.  I'm sure I have a lot to learn from you.  I didn't know you could do JOINs in SQL.  Assume you want to display the following columns character_items.CharacterID, character_items.ItemId, and the columns from table character_item_1, character_item_2, etc.
can you show me what the SELECT clause would look like if I replaced UNIONs with JOINS?

Comment: `SELECT character_items.CharacterID, character_items.ItemId, character_item_1.*, character_item_2.* FROM character_items JOIN character_item_1 ON character_items.ItemID = character_item_1.ItemID JOIN character_item_2 ON character_items.ItemID = character_item_2.ItemID;`

Comment: @Stephen - your SELECT statement assumes there is one and only one row in every table for each character.  If a character doesn't have one of all the item-types, the character will not be included in the results.  If a character has more than one row in any of the item tables, your query will produce multiple rows per character and duplicate data.   hmm, maybe I do know a little bit about JOIN syntaxes.

Comment: In MySQL, joins are LEFT by default.  I should have specified `LEFT JOIN` for clarity (in case you're not using MySQL).  So, in a `LEFT JOIN` the character_items.CharacterID and character_items.ItemId will always return.  Missing table data from other tables will be NULL.  And duplicated data from the character_items table is preferable to multiple selects.  Especially 12 selects.  I hope that helps.  BTW: I'm not attacking you, I'm trying to help you.

Comment: If you're interested in avoiding the duplication, you might try this

SELECT character_items.CharacterID, character_items.ItemId,
 COALESCE(character_items_1.ItemName, character_items_2.ItemName) AS ItemName
FROM character_items 
LEFT OUTER JOIN character_item_1 ON character_items.ItemID = character_item_1.ItemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN character_item_2 ON character_items.ItemID = character_item_2.ItemID
;

It would create similar results to the UNION solution.  In this example the ItemName would appear in one column instead of one column per CharacterItem table.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would try to merge all twelve tables back into one table.

The reason for this is not really anything to do with technical table design -- but rather it will alow your characters to reuse objects in unexpected ways.

You could for instance have a set of throwable attributes such as EFFORT, ACCURACY, DAMAGE, BREAKAGE so a dagger would be almost no effort to throw, and cause a great deal of injury if it stuck its target, on the other hand a goblet would be easy to throw but cause very little damage or a gold bar would be hard to throw but would cuase a reasonable amount of injury even though it is not strictly speaking a weapon.
 It would also allow you to have weapons which were also "treasure" objects of great value or magical use (dont know what sort of game you are planning so these examples may not be appropriate

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still looking for replies, but here is how I did mine very recently:

```
CHARACTER -> Char/Item Link Table -> ITEM

ITEM
----
ID
NAME
TYPE
etc.
```

This allows you to create base items which multiple characters can possess.  If you want to do individual character modification to items (i.e. gem slotting, enchantments, etc.) that can easily be done through an EFFECT table (or something similar):

```
ITEM -> Item/Effect Link Table -> EFFECTS
```

In this manner you can have characters customize their own weapons and still keep the base around.  You can also create a set of effects without having to repeat them over and over for every item in your game.